# anonymous function inside namespace

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm learning Typescript but I'm having a few issues trying to understand a few things.

I have seen this code:

```
module Games {

((): void => {

    alert("");
);
})();
}
```

but when complied to javascript I get the same result if I change it to the bellow:

```
module Games {

    alert("");
})();
}
```

Is there any reason why I would write something like in the first example, or is it just bad code.

Comment: "compiled" is not javascript too.

Comment: Yes, it is not compliled, but when you go to Typescript's official page, they say it is compile.. just wanted to keep it consistent

Comment: also it has syntax error http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XbydME

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So starting with this working example...

```
module Games {
    ((): void => {
        alert("");
    })();
}
```

You *currently* end up with the following result when you compile your TypeScript to JavaScript - the module becomes and immediately invoked function expression...

```
var Games;
(function (Games) {
    (function () {
        alert("");
    })();
})(Games || (Games = {}));
```

Later on when you are targeting a later version of ECMAScript, you may find that the module is actually there in the JavaScript (as this is just early access to a feature that is planned for ECMAScript).

Unless you have a good reason to want that within the module, I would recommend the following adjustment...

```
module Games {

}

((): void => {
    alert("");
})();
```

I think this will survive future changes better.

Comment: Thanks for your help Steve, I got it.

Comment: inline modules rejected in current specs... of ES

Comment: @eicto - yes, the module implementation for ES6 doesn't include any `module` keyword or equivalent structure that would allow TypeScript to preserve closely the original code. You *could* assume that modules will always be compiled into IIFEs... but the suggested code above doesn't rely on predicting the future and will work either way... and it still doesn't add anything to the global scope.

Comment: yes, I just wanted to point that `module {}`  is not in js, may be hapyfully :) But last years there was rumors about inline modules, so you would not use  babelify/browserify to compile code for browser.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, there is no reason to do that.

In more general terms, setting up a function creates a local scope, which allows you to use variables with it in that are not accessible to the rest of the module. This reduces the risk of variables in different parts of the module overwriting each other because they share a name.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation Quentin.